# map.set - array.slice returns too many items

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am working on a vue project and I try to implement pagination for a table.
A bug occurred and I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

I reproduced the problem in a simplified example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rj23rqp2k4

**The problem is that when changing the settings to 10 per page and then back to 5 per page, there are 6 items on the second page instead of 5.**

Html:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="currentPage-=1">Previous</button>
    <button @click="currentPage+=1">Next Page</button>
    <select v-model="perPage">
      <option value="5">5 per page</option>
      <option value="10">10 per page</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <ul v-for="item in pages.get(currentPage)" :key="item">
      <li>
        <strong>{{ item }}</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <h5>Current Page: {{currentPage}}</h5>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",

  data() {
    return {
      data: ["a1","b2","c3","d4","e5","f6","g7","h8","i9","j10","k11"],
      perPage: 5,
      currentPage: 1
    };
  },

  computed: {
    numberOfPages: function() {
      let x = this.data.length / this.perPage;
      if (x % 1 !== 0) {
        x = Math.floor(x) + 1;
      }
      return x;
    },
    pages: function() {
      let pgs = new Map();
      for (
        let index = 0, start = 0, end = this.perPage;
        index < this.numberOfPages;
        index++
      ) {
        pgs.set(index + 1, this.data.slice(start, end));
        start += this.perPage;
        end += this.perPage;
      }
      return pgs;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

*It seems like the bug must be in the pages function as there are 6 items on one page and that shouldn't be the case.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not working anymore after changing the value `perPage` via the dropdown is that the value of `perPage` became a `string` instead of a `number`.

To make it work, convert the value of `this.perPage` to a `number` first before using it like the example below.

```
pages: function() {
  let pgs = new Map();
  const perPage = Number(this.perPage);
  for (
    let index = 0, start = 0, end = perPage;
    index < this.numberOfPages;
    index++
  ) {
    pgs.set(index + 1, this.data.slice(start, end));
    start += perPage;
    end += perPage;
  }
  return pgs;
}
```

You can also adapt @charliefl's solution to make it cleaner but be sure to do the conversion as well.

See [working implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3jnkx4m3p)

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much! I would have never found it. I thought it must be a "logic" issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Since it works perfectly on initial load and the problem only occur after changing the value of `perPage` in the dropdown, it gave me the idea that maybe the issue was `perPage`-related.

Comment: I think this is actually doable with a reduce function. Start looks like the accumulator.

Comment: That's really interesting, how would you implement it using that?

Answer (score 0):

Try just using `start` and add `this.perPage` to it for the end index:

```
 pages: function() {
      let pgs = new Map();
      for (
        let index = 0, start = 0 ;
        index < this.numberOfPages;
        index++
      ) {
        pgs.set(index + 1, this.data.slice(start, start + this.perPage));
        start += this.perPage;           
      }
      return pgs;
    }
```

Comment: yes thanks, this removes the redundant value. However, the issue persists :(